# Making a row in a table fully clickable via html and wordpress functions

Tags: php, javascript, html, wordpress

So I'm trying to make a row fully clickable in a table.  Is there any reason in particular why the first line does not make the whole row a Link?? And if you see the problem please tell me.

```
<tr onclick="DoNav('https://www.math.wisc.edu/undergraduate/mathlab');">
<td align ="center" >
<div id ="org_logo"> <img src =""width = "150"; </div> 
Math Lab
</td>
<td> 
Math 101, 112, 113, 114, 141, 171, 211, 213, 221, 222, 234, 240
</td>
<td>
Mathlab is a free, drop-in tutorial program of the Department of Mathematics. It is      primarily staffed by Mathematics Department teaching assistants. Mathlab is open both in the fall and spring semesters of each academic year, but is closed during the summer sessions. In Mathlab, students work together with other students in the same course. Mathlab assistants help with one or two homework problems at a time, or with key examples from the text. </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Apply it to the `td`s and it'll work. `tr`s are obscured by the `td`s

Comment: I fixed my img src and tried switching the onclick over to the td...still no luck.

Comment: Would the onclicks functionality be changed if the text is output via php by a loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DoNav is a PHP function, which is server-side. You can't call it from onclick. Instead, use JavaScript to set the document location to the destination.

You should probably use CSS to format your table rather than align="center" and use underlines to indicate to a user that the row is a link, but, regardless, the following code works:

```
 <table>    
       <tr onclick="document.location='https://www.math.wisc.edu/undergraduate/mathlab';">
          <td align="center" >
             <div id ="org_logo"><img src ="" width = "150" alt="Math Lab Logo"></div> 
             Math Lab
         </td>
         <td> 
            Math 101, 112, 113, 114, 141, 171, 211, 213, 221, 222, 234, 240
        </td>
        <td>
        Mathlab is a free, drop-in tutorial program of the Department of Mathematics. It is  primarily staffed by Mathematics Department teaching assistants. Mathlab is open both in the fall and spring semesters of each academic year, but is closed during the summer sessions. In Mathlab, students work together with other students in the same course. Mathlab assistants help with one or two homework problems at a time, or with key examples from the text.
      </td>
     </tr>  
    </table>
```